# Does doing an export moves all my posts or just a copy of it?

Tags: export

I want to move from Wordpress hosting to self-hosting. I have installed wordpress on my self-host account. Now I want to play with it for a while with themes,plugins, etc. and see how it goes. So I am thinking of bringing all my post to my account.

I would like my original blog on wordpress to work as usual for now until I am ready to redirect it to my own domain/host.

**Question:**
So when I use the Export facility (All post) will the posts get permanently removed from my blog or will it be just a copy of my posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a copy of your posts.

Comment: Thanks. I had an extra unused blog with two posts. I tried on that and yep indeed it's just the copy.